# Como criar confirms Artisan Command Laravel recursivamente?

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Deseja incrementar mais um? (yes/no) [no]:

> yes

contador = : 1

Deseja incrementar mais um? (yes/no) [no]:

> yes

contador = : 2

Deseja incrementar mais um? (yes/no) [no]:

> no

Pesquisa finalizada.

Comment: Isso não parece ser um problema recursivo. Apenas um laço de repetição já supre sua necessidade: `while ($this->confirm('...')) { ... }`

Comment: Sim @Woss concordo,  mas você pode colocar toda sua logica dentro do while,   o detalhe é que vi alguém com esta dúvida e um pessoa disse não ter como realizar perguntas sequenciais,   mas não achei mais o  post dela!

Answer (score 2):

```
//Para fazer isso, podemos usar um laço while,  da seguinte maneira:


public function handle()
{

        $contador = 0;
        $confirmado = true;

        while ($confirmado) {
            if ($this->confirm('Deseja incrementar mais um?')) {
                $contador++;
                $this->info('contador = : '.$contador);
            } else {
                $confirmado = false;
            }
        }
}
```